# How to determine which motors give me faster acceleration to a speed?

Tags: motor, dc-motor, h-bridge

I have two motors for one system, assume that I do not allow to do experiment to fund the answer.

One of them is 
http://www.servocomponents.com/Pittman-Brush-Motor-14000-series/14207s008-SP

The other one is
http://www.servocomponents.com/Pittman-Brush-Motor-9000-series/9237s011-SP

They connect to a 0.3520 [oz·in 2] system respectively.

Which one will accelerate faster to reach 1500 rpm?

When I study this problem, I know that there are two parts.

One is the mechanical which is the torque, inertia part.

The other part is the electrical part, which has the back EMF, internal resistance, etc.

How to find the answer?

Comment: Why is there an inches squared on your torque? I assume that's just a typo.

Comment: @DKNguyen he probably means the moment of inertia of the load.  But clarification would be good.

Comment: @TimWescott I think you're right. I'm not used to seeing moment of inertia in imperial units. That makes my second simplified answer invalid then since you can't neglect load. OTOH, that means my first answer that assumed load inertia was dominant becomes valid again. You can pretty much neglect rotor inertia so the motor that outputs the most torque wins.

Comment: Working in the US I've gotten used to doing things like saying "oh, mass or weight times distance times time-squared!  It must be inertia, and that must be mass!".  At least we don't use statvolts anymore...

Comment: @TimWescott A slug is the dumbest unit ever.

Comment: I prefer slugs to systems where people mix pound-mass and pound-force, and leave it up to me to intuit the difference.  Besides, coming from a part of the US that's moist and temperate, slugs (the animal kind) are a part of my life.

Comment: It's finally starting to change, but for the past ~40 years, the military has been measuring coating thicknesses in the units of grams per square foot.

Answer (score 0):

You can neglect the electrical time constants since they are so much faster than mechanical side of things.

You have an unusually large amount of information for your motors which is good because it makes this easy. Your load inertia dwarfs the listed rotor inertia of both motors, so you can neglect it. That means the motor with the most torque will accelerate up to speed fastest.

You don't need to consider the motor needing to accelerate itself until its rotor inertia becomes comparable to your load inertia. In this case, you would add your your load and rotor inertias together to get the total inertia. Then compare the ratio between torque and total inertia of both motors against each other.

In this case, the Series 9000 is about ~64000 torque/moment of inertia and the Series 14000 motor is ~60,000 torque/moment of inertia. So the series 9000 will get up to speed slightly faster.

Note that we can use just a single torque point here for this comparison rather than actually taking into account how torque varies with RPM and calculating out the exact acceleration over time because these are DC motors with a linear torque curve. It won't work for hold true for motors with non-linear torque curves (like induction motors). You'll actually have to calculate everything out in that case.

**EDIT:** Thanks to Phil G since I did not even notice that the datasheets listed electrical and mechanical time constants. I was just working on the generalization that electrical time constants are usually much much faster than mechanical ones. The time constants are actually a lot closer than I would have guessed, but the electrical time constant is still significantly faster.

Comment: But the one with more torque should have more wire, that mean more core. This will make the rate of change of the current low. This will hurt the response, isn't it.

Comment: Think about a RL circuit, what will time response change if L increases.

Comment: @Superhero Sure, but then what of the time it takes to actually accelerate the motor due to inertia? The LC time constant is so much faster than that that its negligible. Not to mention that your question specifically asks up accelerating up to speed.

Comment: But the inertia of a motor should be related to torque output. When you pick a higher torque output motor, it may have delay in electrical response and delay in acceleration because of the higher inertia value

Comment: @Superhero Well, the delay in electrical response is so fast compared to the mechanical side of things so you can just consider that to be negligible in this scenario. Your load inertia also dwarfs your rotor inertia so you can neglect rotor inertia. That means that the motor with the highest output torque that can still reach the desired RPM will get there fastest. If your rotor inertia was significant relative to your load inertia, then you would have to start considering it, but it's not in your case.

Answer (score 0):

The datasheets in the linked pages give you the data you need for this. The electrical time constants are a couple of milliseconds, so as long as your first pass at the acceleration time due to mechanical constraints gives a time many times more than this, you can ignore this.

These brushed motors have an almost straight line relationship between torque and speed, intersecting the speed axis at the peak torque, and the torque axis at the no load speed quoted. You can deduce from that a y=ax+b equation for the torque-speed relationship, and knowing the inertia you are accelerating (external load plus the motor rotor's own inertia) you can calculate the instantaneous acceleration, and solve for time to reach a given speed - the speed curve is an exponential decay aiming to the no load speed as an asymptote. You already know that your target speed is below the no load speed for both, so the time is definite.